# Getting Whenever to Work with RVM and Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, whenever

I'm deploying an app that uses capistrano/whenever/rvm. Apparently, the whenever/rvm combo has a gotcha, as documented [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/RVM-Notes). The wiki describes three ways of overcoming this. I've tried all of them and to no avail. These solutions include setting `rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1` in `~/.rvmrc`, configuring `schedule.rb` to use the proper capistrano route, and using an alternative whenever gem. Again, none of these solutions have worked for me.

Checking `crontab -e`, whenever is successfully creating the cron jobs. According to the system logs, they're even being executed. However, they're not actually running in Rails. One debugging task reads like this:

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "Company::Category.create(name: 'Shoe Cleaning')"
end
```

However, no `Company::Category` is created. Any advice for better debugging this? I've been on it for nearly 7 hours now and I'm struggling to move forward.

Comment: What do the Rails logs show?  Anything?

Comment: The production logs didn't show anything. I ended up scrapping RVM and used [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), instead. It works perfectly here.